# iOS Swift CNContactPickerViewController search contact and add to selection

Tags: ios, search, swift2, cncontact, contactpicker

### I am using iOS 9 and Swift 2.2

I have implemented iOS inbuilt `CNContactPickerViewController` using `CNContactPickerDelegate` to get the contact numbers,

In the `CNContactPickerViewController` Screen, when I click on search field on top and search for a name, I need to add that name to my selection but nothing happens after tapping the contact.

I searched everywhere and dint find any solution to this

Do I need to add anything to my code or is it a iOS 9 bug

```
@IBAction func AddBtnKlkFnc(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
        [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
    self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts ContctAryVar: [CNContact])
{
    for ContctVar in ContctAryVar
    {
        let ContctDtlVar = ContctDtlCls()
        ContctDtlVar.ManNamVar = CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(ContctVar, style: .FullName)!

        for ContctNumVar: CNLabeledValue in ContctVar.phoneNumbers
        {
            var MobNumVar  = ((ContctNumVar.value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as? String)!
            if(MobNumVar.Len() > 10)
            {
                MobNumVar = MobNumVar.GetLstSubSrgFnc(10)
            }
            ContctDtlVar.MobNumVar = MobNumVar
            ContctDtlAryVar.append(ContctDtlVar)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a known issue: see http://openradar.me/25433471.

Comment: I just want to confirm that this has not been fixed in iOS 10.

Comment: Nop It has not been fixed even in iOS 10.2

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 10.3.1 !!!

Comment: Hii Sujay. Did you solve that issue? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Use this updated code and  


   @IBAction func AddBtnKlkFnc(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self
        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
            [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
        self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts ContctAryVar: [CNContact])
    {
        for ContctVar in ContctAryVar
        {
            let ContctDtlVar = ContctDtlCls()
            ContctDtlVar.ManNamVar = CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(ContctVar, style: .FullName)!

            for ContctNumVar: CNLabeledValue in ContctVar.phoneNumbers
            {
                var MobNumVar  = ((ContctNumVar.value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as? String)!
                if(MobNumVar.Len() > 10)
                {
                    MobNumVar = MobNumVar.GetLstSubSrgFnc(10)
                }
                ContctDtlVar.MobNumVar = MobNumVar
                ContctDtlAryVar.append(ContctDtlVar)
            }
        }

     delegate.didFetchContacts([contact])
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Comment: here wat is a delegate.  i am getting this "Use of unresolved identifier 'delegate'" how to slove that

Answer (score 11):

The search results seem to be working in single selection mode only, so make sure you implement

```
func contactPicker(CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect: CNContact)
```

only, but not

```
func contactPicker(CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect: [CNContact])
```

If you implement both, the version wich takes only one `CNContact` as argument is ignored and the multi selection mode is used instead.

Comment: Brilliant! I would like to add 100 to this response thank you very much @bbjay

Comment: It isn't working for me, delegate method

func contactPicker(CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect: CNContact)

never gets called while selection after search

Comment: @iOSMonster did you setup your delegate correctly? maybe ask a new question and show your code

Answer (score 2):

Here is a **swift 4** version

```
@IBAction func addPhoneContact(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPicker.delegate = self
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
        [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
    self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

extension ViewController: CNContactPickerDelegate {
  func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
      picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      let name = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName)
      for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
        let mobile = number.value.value(forKey: "digits") as? String
        if (mobile?.count)! > 7 {
            // your code goes here
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Multi selection and  search are mutually exclusive. If you want search to be working you have to go with single selection only and implement only single selection delegate method.