# contact selection not possible when using the search bar

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, cncontact, contactpicker

Im using the ContactPickerViewController with CNContactPickerDelegate to get the contact numbers

```
    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController,
                       didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]) 
    {...}
```

but when I try to use the search bar to find a contact , the selection box disappear (also if I click on the relevant cell , the contact remain unselected)

[image: without using the search bar everything work fine]

[image: when trying to use the search bar]

thanks for your help!

Comment: Hii Jerem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Swift CNContactPickerViewController search contact and add to selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143951/ios-swift-cncontactpickerviewcontroller-search-contact-and-add-to-selection)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like its a bug in iOS 9. It has been reported.

Check the discussion thread here
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/87148#87148

You could try using other open source alternatives

EPContactsPicker - https://github.com/ipraba/EPContactsPicker

Or write your own tableview that implements the functionality.

Comment: Has this ever been fixed? I think it is still the same in Xcode 9 and iOS 11. Bizarre!

Comment: Bug still exists. I guess Apple wants to keep a sign there :)

Comment: How long can this go on? Still exists on XCode 10, iOS 12.

Comment: see my solution over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354184/2107610