# Hide or Disable searchbar in CNContactPickerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I came to know that search bar in `CNContactPickerViewController` doesn't allow to select searched contacts. I also look other stack overflow questions regarding this issue. It seems like iOS bug. But I want to know, is there any way to hide or disable search bar from `CNContactPickerViewController`? Because if this doesn't work then I don't want to show it.

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141210/how-to-hide-remove-the-search-bar-on-contact-picker

Comment: Saurabh, that is in objective-c, i need the response in swift 3.

Comment: I have the same issue, I wish to hide the search bar on the CNContactPickerViewController because the search box is useless!

Comment: It's not useless when you have 300 contacts ...

Answer (score 0):

```
private var foundSearchBar: Bool = false

func findSearchBar(_ parent: UIView, mark: String) {
    for v: UIView in parent.subviews {
        //if( foundSearchBar ) return;
        print("\(mark)\(NSStringFromClass(v.self))")
        if (v is UISearchBar) {
            (v as? UISearchBar)?.tintColor = UIColor.black
            v.hidden = true
            //            foundSearchBar = YES;
            break
        }
        if (v is UITableView) {
            let temp: CGRect = v.frame
            temp.origin.y = temp.origin.y - 44
            temp.size.height = temp.size.height + 44
            v.frame = temp
            //foundSearchBar = YES;
            break
        }
        findSearchBar(v, mark: mark + ("> "))
    }
}
```

call above method after picker is presented as below:

```
func showPeoplePickerController() {
    let picker = ABPeoplePickerNavigationController()
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self
    picker.view.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
        // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
    let displayedItems: [Any] = [Int(kABPersonPhoneProperty), Int(kABPersonEmailProperty), Int(kABPersonBirthdayProperty), Int(kABPersonAddressProperty)]
    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems
    // Show the picker
    present(picker, animated: true) { _ in }
    findSearchBar(picker.view(), mark: "> ")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this code is not working for me, as i am using CNContactPickerViewController, instead of ABAddressbook. So migt be there is change in there view and subviews, as per my code i am unable to satisfy that for loop, its not going inside that loop and its showing 0 elements, when i am printing parent.subviews value.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Not yet :( @RichaGupta

Comment: @RichaGupta have you found the solution?

Comment: Not working for me, the subviews array seems to be empty :(

Comment: @AndreaGorrieri The answer is too old and i Forgot

Comment: As the CNContactPickerViewController is a UIRemoteView you have no access to it

Answer (score 0):

As you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354184/2610888) the problem seems to be present only if you use the multi-contact selection mode for the CNContactPickerViewController. Implementing the single-contact selection mode you can search for a contact and select it without problems. In order to use the single-contact selection mode make sure you implement in your CNContactPickerDelegate **ONLY** this method:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
```

and not this method:

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact])
```

Implementing both methods the multi-selection mode is used.